# Good programs to reverse video clips

Tags: windows-7, video, software-rec

What are some good programs that will enable me to reverse my video clips?

Comment: Do you mean for the video clips playing backwards or change the format of i.e. AVI file into OGP file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used Adobe Premiere to reverse video in the past.  This is not the cheapest solution, but works very well.  You can reverse a video by using the Time Stretch tool, this is selected by right clicking on the clip and selecting Time Stretch. Once selected tick the Reverse Speed box and the video will play from the end to the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Several free programs now recognize a text-based scripting language for editing movies... called Avisynth. You just type a few simple text commands for what you want to do, and the program interprets the text file and makes your movie. You don't have to learn the whole language... I just copy and paste examples of whatever I need.

The avisynth script would just be a single line of text:

Reverse(AVISource("C:\yourfile.avi"))

That's assuming the file is an AVI. But it can take other formats too. For example, an mpeg would be

Reverse(ffmpegsource("C:\yourfile.mpg"))

edit: you would save this one line of text in a file named whatever.avs and then open the AVS file in your chosen program.

It's up to you what program to use, some are more user friendly than others. Programs that can accept avisynth scripts include Virtualdub, staxrip, and megui. There are others, it kind of depends on your input file. Virtualdub's good for avi's, and virtualdubmod can accept other formats. Staxrip is really user friendly. Megui is a little daunting, but can handle almost everything and output to a ton of different formats.